# Components disappearing after setting visable to false and then to true again

Tags: java, swing

i have this program with a small amount of settings, and it should look like this:
http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/8527/programbillede.png (sorry, cant post images..)
and this is loaded in main and then hidden, and then when i run through some other functions, and try to show this again, then it looks like this:
http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/6886/programbillede1.png (sorry, cant post images..)
the few buttons that are visible are because when you mouse over this then you can see them, but you can never get to see the 3 labels... help .. :)

any questions then ask .. :)

this is how i call the settings thing .. doMain just hides the main menu parts.

```
}else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Indstillinger")){
        doMain(false);
        Exit.setVisible(true);
        Exit.setBounds(650, 135, 70, 20);
        returntomain.setVisible(true);
        settings.setvisable(true);
```

ops .. forgot the settings.setvisable looks like this..

```
public void setvisable(boolean doWhat){
    panel1.setVisible(doWhat);
    panel2.setVisible(doWhat);
    panel3.setVisible(doWhat);
}
```

and this is the only thing which accesses anything from my settings..

```
private Image tilfojbillede(int nr) throws IOException{
    String navn=("/Resources/"+Indstillinger.BilledeMappe+"/"+(nr+1)+".png");
    return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(navn));
}
```

and the settings consists of 3 panels made like this in a constructor...

```
    panel1.setBounds(50, 150, 150, 200);
    panel1.setVisible(false);
    panel2.setBounds(200, 150, 150, 100);
    panel2.setVisible(false);
    panel3.setBounds(350, 150, 150, 200);
    panel3.setVisible(false);
```

and i call these 2 classes in my main, as a global function like this...

```
    public static Indstillinger settings= new Indstillinger();
    public static Spillet spillet= new Spillet();
```

i hope you guys can help me from this information ..

Comment: Plase post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Otherwise there is no way we can help you.

Comment: Let's see some of the offending code. Try to make it as small as possible such that it 1) compiles and 2) illustrates the problem.

Comment: (Just a guess) Try calling `revalidate` on the container of the components whose visibility you are changing. You need to call `revalidate` whenever you make a layout change, and I think invisible elements have zero size, so that would be a layout change.

Comment: the revalidate did not work, just tried to call it on all 3 panels.. did not work .. sadly.. :)

Comment: well, you did say the containers, which isnt the 3 panels, but the JFrame, but i cannot call revalidate on main, as in this.revalidate in the main class, or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: hmmm `settings.setvisable(true);` must be `settings.setVisible(true);`

Comment: `panel1.setBounds(50, 150, 150, 200); .... etc` is great job for GridLaout -->  [http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html]

Comment: Can you post a link to the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `revalidate();` and maybe `repaint();` as well.

Comment: i cannot call that... i get a error if i call it in main and if i call it in my settings class..